# Embed Google Map but hide pin's label? 

Tags: google-maps

Im embedding a google map into a page with the simple iframe method. Is there a way I can hide the label by the pin that contains the address?

The label just says 'A' which isnt helpful for me, especially as im embedding 2 maps, both of which have the 'A'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `&iwloc=near` at the end of the iframe src string